# How can two electrons form the anti-symmetrical state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, identical-particles

Suppose that I have two electrons in a box that were originally spread by a infinite potential wall. The two electrons are in their ground state wave function (sine function).

Now I removed the barrier for the two electrons to interact. How is the Pauli antisymmetrical pair formed? Do I have to impose them to become the antisymmetrical pair  in the beginning, or can I derive the antisymmetrical form from the original sine functions?

Answer (score 7):

The antisymmetry of the two-particle wavefunction must be imposed by hand from the very beginning, even when the particles are constrained to occupy different spatial regions. As long as the Hamiltonian is compatible with the identical particles requirement (i.e. it commutes with the particle exchange operator), then the state will remain antisymmetric under the corresponding time evolution.

It's important to appreciate the precise, technical meaning of indistinguishability. In quantum mechanics, we call a system of particles *indistinguishable* if the state of the system is necessarily unchanged by the exchange of any pair of particles. In $3+1$ dimensions, the [Spin-Statistics Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem) asserts that there are only two possibilities - either the $N$-particle wavefunction is totally symmetric, or it is totally antisymmetric. The former class of particles are called *bosons*, and the latter are called *fermions*.

If you have a system of fermionic particles, then the $N$-particle wavefunction must be fully antisymmetric under particle exchange. There are no other options. If your wavefunction is not fully antisymmetric, it does not describe a system of fermions.

Whether the requirement of antisymmetry has observable consequences on the system is a different question. If, as in your initial state, a pair of particles is constrained such that they are restricted to non-overlapping regions of space, then the indistinguishability of your particles has no observable consequences (for local observables). As a result, you'd get the same predictions as if you dropped the antisymmetry requirement. Such a system might be called *effectively distinguishable* - which you should interpret as meaning that you may as well treat them as distinguishable particles for convenience, even though they aren't.

More generally, if the wavefunction of the 2-particle system takes the form
$$\Psi(x_1,x_2) = \psi(x_1)\phi(x_2) - \psi(x_2)\phi(x_1)$$

and $\langle \psi,\phi\rangle \ll 1$, the particles are effectively distinguishable. This holds for particles which are localized to different regions of space, as well as particles with very different quantum numbers. However, the ability to get the "right answers" by treating the particles as distinguishable is predicated on the assumption that their states will *always* satisfy these requirements, which is a strong assumption. Furthermore, even if you can treat them as distinguishable for the sake of easy calculations, it is worth remembering that this is a shortcut and that the true state of the system is **always** antisymmetric.

Comment: Well, there is the concept of effective indsitinguishability. So if both particles can be confined in separate spatial regions, one can treat them as distinguishable.

Comment: So as long as I removed the barrier, two electrons just automatically form an anti symmetrical pair? Is there a time process for it to happen?

Comment: I'm not sure this is completely correct.  Consider the conceptually similar example of 2 photons produced by 2 different lasers: the initial pulses will be distinguishable and the 2-photon state will be unsymmetrized product state.  It's only once the pulses overlap (say inside an interferometer or in some interaction region) that distinguishability is lost.  A good example of this is the initial state of the [HOM effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect#Mathematical_description) which is clearly separable as photons are emitted from distinct sources.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I have expanded my answer to address the question of effective or approximate indistinguishability.

Comment: Don't you mean *effectively distinguishable* rather than *effectively indistinguishable*?  Likewise for your "approximately indistinguishable"?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes, thanks. With regard to your original comment, I would make the point that indistinguishability is not a property of a state. A pair of photons on opposite sides of the galaxy are still indistinguishable. That doesn't mean that you can't tell that there are two, or that you can't track the trajectory of one of them; it means that they don't have identities. In other words, the state is "there are two photons, one on either side of the galaxy" rather than "photon A is on one side of the galaxy and photon B is on the other" (where A and B technically refer to the first [...]

Comment: [...] and second factor of the tensor-product Hilbert space).

Comment: @Neonslayer To clarify/reiterate, two electrons must be in an antisymmetric state *at all times*. There is no antisymmetrization process - it is simply always the case. Whether or not that has tangible consequences for the system may vary over time, though.

Comment: Well... there is a distinction between "identical" and "indistinguishable".  Two electrons at either end of the galaxy are certainly identical, but distinguishable.  You hit the nail right on the head by invoking the permutation group: indistinguishable more or less means a 1-dimensional irrep of the permutation group.  Of course identical is a precondition for any notion of indistinguishability.

Comment: There is work by Kaplan (see [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/PU1975v018n12ABEH005246/pdf) and [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-013-9742-4) ) about this but I'm too lazy right now to reread this.  There's also [Bach](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf00734566) on related topics.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Two electrons on either end of the galaxy are identical (same mass, charge, spin, etc) **and** indistinguishable (their state is invariant under their interchange), both of which are implied by the stronger statement that they are *fermions* (transform under the non-trivial 1D irrep of the permutation group), as per Bach's definitions. What definition of "distinguishable" do you prefer, that would apply to those electrons?

Answer (score 0):

A system of two electrons separated by an infinite potential barrier may be described as a pair of distinguishable particles, or as a pair of indistinguishable particles. You have to choose.

If you choose distinguishable particles (which has some merit in case of an infinite potential barrier), thus the initial psi function is neither antisymmetric nor symmetric, then the evolution based on the Hamiltonian where the particles are identical cannot change the psi function into a symmetric or antisymmetric function. So in a mathematical sense, there will not be any continuous transformation of distinguishable pair into an indistinguishable pair; the pair will remain distinguishable in principle. Unless the evolution is not Hamiltonian (removal of the infinite barrier seems kind of problematic, but probably it can still be consistently described via a Hamiltonian evolution).

However, it is possible that the evolved function will be so complex that this remaining distinguishability will be a fine detail of the function, and predictions of measurements based on this evolved psi function will be the same as for an antisymmetric function appropriate for the new macroscopic constraints (no barrier).

This reminds me of the "problem" of Gibbs entropy non-increase in statistical physics. The Hamiltonian evolution of the probability distribution (or density matrix) of a multi-particle interacting system does not change the [Gibbs/von Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy); the system keeps all the initial information and the same information entropy. This also happens in the case where a wall is removed and two gases are allowed to mix. But the descriptor function $\rho$ undergoes such a complicated change that the resulting predictions (expected averages) are almost the same as those for a different, smoother and simpler function $\rho_{eff}$ (and also symmetric in any pair of identical particles), estimated as the maximum entropy function for the new constraints (no potential barrier).